# Enable submit button in bootstrapvalidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using bootstrapvalidator to validate my application from here https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator . I would like to keep the submit button enabled even before validation has taken place.
How can i go about this in bootstrapvalidator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download the latest boostrapValidator and check the sample [here](https://rawgithub.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/master/demo/submitHandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

See this link, Actually I have ajax call in form on click event not submit event.
Because your validator is working with input field but onClick is not working or isValid all input field
Check the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/varsadadj/wLGRh/1/

```
$("#login").on('click',function(){
      $(".form-horizontal").bootstrapValidator();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have just one option to fix it:

- Change 90 line in bootstrapValidator.js to:

  that.$form.find(that.options.submitButtons).attr('enabled', 'enabled');

Comment: I don't think OP or anyone would prefer to modify source code to solve issues like this, until and unless it is impossible in the framework.